# Use php to execute a command in terminal

Tags: php

Hello Im trying to create a php that executes a command in terminal. I dont know why but my code does not work.

When I go to ..../api.php?link=hello
it does not create the folder with that name

```
<?php
$parameter = $_GET['link'];
$output = shell_exec('sudo mkdir $parameter');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Fixed my command was not running because I had to put "sudo mkdir $parameter" not 'sudo mkdir $parameter' because my $parameter had symbols that confused the command. Thanks everyone for helping me figuring this out!

Comment: This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: add **2>&1** to see the error

Comment: follow this link https://www.codexpedia.com/php/running-php-code-on-terminal-window/

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of shell_execute (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), You need to disabel safe mode.

**On linux servers**

1. Run the following command:

   ```
   `vi /etc/php.ini`
   ```
2. Go to the line safe_mode = on and press the "i" key.
3. Change the line to safe_mode = off and press the "Esc" key.
4. Type :wq! to save your file.

**On Windows Servers**

1. Open c:\windowsphp.ini in Notepad.
2. Change the line safe_mode = on to safe_mode = off.
3. Save and close php.ini.

Comment: My php.ini does not have a safe_mode line just a sql.safe_mode

Comment: Can you check with this code:

if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
   // safe mode is on
}else{
   // it's not
}

Comment: ah forgive me, php safe mode has been  DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking , to problem is due to the permission , so here is the solution :

Let's suppose your file php that contain the exec command exist inside a folder nammed src

```
src/api.php
```

The src folder should have as owner www-data:www-data instead of something else to make php able to exec command .

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo mkdir $parameter  2>&1');
```

Add  **2>&1** to see the error occuring inside .

> When modifying the permission , you can exec the command, but be ware
>   that the file or folder yu are creating should be inside the src
>   folder , if it's another place , the parent folder should have as
>   owner **www-data:www-data**

Comment: The output I get is We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified